# Can't forward a port

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, ddns

I spend a day searching in how to forward a port from my router to my PC, whihout success. And now I'm out of leads... and frustrated. I've seen many pages with descriptions and possible solutions but somehow I don't see the right answer. So, excusses if this is a repeating question, that is not how I see it.

This is what I try to do:
I want to have access to my PC at home when I'm at work. For this I use a ddns service.

Some scenarios that work, and some that dont:
This is my `standard' configuration.

I have two PC's, a desktop and a laptop. On both I have an SSH server (bitvise) and an SSH client (PuTTY) The desktop is running windows 10 and the laptop is running windows 7. I can make a SSH connection from the desktop to the laptop and the other way around, suggesting to me that port 22 is open on both computer. Right?

```
ISP
 |
ZyXEL VMG8324-B10A (forward port 22 to 192.168.1.105)
 | .1  (192.168.1.x)
 |
 +- .105 PC (desktop, W10, SSH server on port 22)
 |
 +- .107 PC (laptop, W7, SSH server on port 22)
```

The service for ddns allows me to connect to my home network. If I try to connect port 80 I just get the login screen for my router, no problems there. I even tried it with a second routeron confifured for port 8080 and the original server forwarding port 8080 to this second server. No problem.

This is what that setup does look like.

```
ISP
 |
ZyXEL VMG8324-B10A (forward port 8080 to 192.168.1.2)
 | .1  (192.168.1.x)
 |
 | .2
LinkSys E3000 (configuration available on port 8080)
 | .1  (10.233.1.x)
```

I was successfull in connecting to the configuration for LinkSys (on port 8080) via the ddns provider. No problems there. Right?

As said before, I can establish a connection between 192.168.1.105 SSH client to 192.168.1.107 SSH server and also 192.168.1.107 SSH client to 192.168.1.105 SSH server.

But I can't get a connection via ddns to any SSH server.

Now, I can see the configuration page (port 80) for ZyXEL and for LinkSys E3000 (forwarding port 8080 works). Why does it not work for port 22?

Here are the rules in ZyXEL for the forwarding:

```
# Status Name      WAN WAN_IP ServerIP      TriggerStart End TranslationStart End Protocol
1 active SSH       wan -      192.168.1.105 22           22   22           22   TCP/UDP
2 active http8080  wan -      192.168.1.105 8080         8080 8080         8080 TCP/UDP
```

Nothing strange here. And SSH communication between PC and laptop possible, nothing strange there. Where do I have to look for communication from ddns to PC? What do I forget?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Edit: 5 sept 2016.

Problem solved! With the help form the answers below I was able to iron out some configuration issues and a few minutes ago I was able to get a RDC going from my android to my PC. Nice!

Comment: Complete instructions at [Port Forwarding the ZyXEL VMG8324-B10A Router for SSH](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZyXEL/VMG8324-B10A/SSH.htm)

Comment: From where did you try connecting? Inside your local network?

Comment: @Daniel B: I tried to connect from the inside (laptop -> ddns provider -> PC).

Comment: Just found out at work that I cannot ping my home network.
Also found out that traceroute from http://ping.eu/traceroute/ to my home IP address is not working. And I'm using the WAN IP adres, not one from the inside, that would be silly.
Maybe it is time to ask my ISP some questions.

Comment: Just got remote access to port 80 on the ZyXEL going! The configuration for enabling http access is a bit hidden (menu 'Maintenance' -> 'Remote MGMT'). Switched it on and tested access via my smartphone. Got the login form. Good enough for proof that the ddns service is working. So I switched it off again. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you’re inside the network and the following happens:

> The service for ddns allows me to connect to my home network. If I try to connect port 80 I just get the login screen for my router

That means your router does not support NAT loopback. To properly test your port forwarding, you need to be outside the local network. You could use your phone with mobile broadband to test, for example.

Ping is filtered by default on most consumer-grade routers. That’s security through obscurity, of course. It also makes diagnosing issues needlessly difficult, so you can just disable that option.

Also:
Your router’s internal software is also not behaving properly. The web interface opens when you browse to your external IP address. This is very dangerous! Without knowing your internal network structure, an attacker can gain control of your router via cross-site scripting or the like.

Comment: I do not know if port 80 is available on the WAN side of the ZyXEL, I find the documentation a bit obscure on that point. I will certainly close it if I can. I was using port 80 and 8080 for testing purposes. I know it is available on the inside and on the Linksys E3000 the configuration for it is much easier. 
Thank you very much for the suggestion to use my mobile phone, I did not think about that before!
Testing on the outside today showed me that it is *not* working, not on port 80 and also not on port 22. I will wait for the anwers and advise from my ISP before I continue.

Comment: It’s probably not available on the WAN side. However, this is accomplished purely using firewall rules. Rules that don’t apply because your packet isn’t coming from the Internet. That means you need to “execute the exploit yourself“. Which is as easy as visiting a website. // Did you set up the SSH port forwarding on both routers? You should also consider getting rid of double NAT, it’s not a good setup.

Comment: Suggesting to use my phone just made the difference. All other text (in both answers) is very helpfull and informative. But being able to test efficiently and in the right way was the road to success for me.

Answer (score 0):

> "I can make a SSH connection from the desktop to the laptop and the other way around, suggesting to me that port 22 is open on both computer. Right?"

Yes.  This indicates that the SSH server is running, and no software-based firewall (on either machine) is blocking that traffic.

Note that this does not mean that you can SSH in from another network.  Windows Firewall can have different rules apply depending on whether a network appears to be "Private", "Public", or "Guest".  So just because the software firewall allows one connection doesn't mean that another connection will work.  I'm not suggesting that this is likely to be the source of your problem, but if it is, it can be very tricky to detect if you don't think about it.

Let me also make sure you have an understanding of what an "open port" is.  We're referring to TCP port numbers and UDP port numbers.  These "ports" are simply numbers.  When a "port" is open, that means that a connection can be made to that port.

So, when someone tries to send an SSH request to your home's IP address, your ISP will dutifully pass that traffic onto the router in your building.  If the result is a successful connection, then the port is open.

Now, there are two ways that the router can handle that traffic in a way that makes the port be open.

- One of those ways is for the router to be running a program that responds to that port.  So, for port 22, that would typically mean that the router would be running an SSH server.  (And, for port 80, that would typically mean that the router is running an HTTP server, which we often call a "web server".)
- The other possible approach is for the router to pass along the traffic to another device.  This is typically done by sending traffic to a device on another subnet.  When the device does this, it "routes" the traffic.  That is why we often call these things a "router".

In order for the second approach to work, the router needs to know what system to send the traffic to.  This can be done using a process called "port forwarding".  All "port forwarding" really involves is telling the router what port number the traffic is expected to arrive on, and then what system the traffic goes to.

Now, if you check your router configuration, you might find that your "port forwarding" section is blank.  So, how can SSH be routed in that case?  Well, many routers have a configuration section called a "demilitarized zone", very often abbreviated "DMZ".  The way this DMZ works is really just a rather special rule for port forwarding.  You end up specifying what computer the router will use, and the router will send all ports to that computer, unless there is a more specific rule specified in the "port forwarding" section.  I think most routers don't usually place the DMZ into the port forwarding section, perhaps because the DMZ configuration might cause the router to forward IP traffic other than just those ports.

In general, you can only do one thing with incoming traffic on port 22.  Okay, so I suppose it is possible to do more than one thing, like have traffic from an office in Seattle to go to a laptop while traffic from Tokyo goes to the desktop.  However, such complicated setups are not common.  What would be far more common is to just have port forwarding send a different port (e.g. maybe 2222) to your other machine and have that machine listen on a non-standard port.

(Or have the router do some translation, so incoming traffic on port 2222 gets redirected to the other machine's standard port 22.  But then the machine that receives the traffic doesn't even have to know that port 2222 got used.  Hiding such information can make logs be less useful, and then you'd need to remember that the router is doing such translation.  Instead, of you just listen to port 2222, things are often more clear.)

Note that ICMP (used by ping, and multiple traceroute implementations) does not use a TCP port or a UDP port.  (ICMP sits above IP.  However, even though IP uses "Layer 3" of the OSI networking model, ICMP doesn't really qualify as being a protocol that is on "Layer 4" of the OSI Model, because it does not provide the typical conversation-tracking feature that tends to distinguish a "Layer 4" protocol.)

So now you see that having your port 22 open on the router won't necessarily help both machines to get SSH traffic.

Understand that your ZyXEL likely has two IPv4 addresses (assuming your Internet is using IPv4).  One is the 192.168.1.1.  That address is safe to tell us about, because it is an address listed in [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918).  The other is a public address.  It sounds like that address changes (since you use DynDNS).  Don't tell us that address.  (For conversation, you can pretend like it starts with "203.0.113.", which is actually a set of addresses reserved for examples/documentation, as noted by [RFC 5735 page 5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735#page-5).)

You may have an easier time by just not using Dynamic DNS, but getting a static IP from your ISP.  I know of an ISP local where I am (in the USA) that can give out a static IP (to a customer) on request, free of charge.  They might want to charge you (and, if so, you might want also ask what the price is for a /29, which is a block of 8, of which 5 are typically usable by the customer).  This isn't to suggest that your route of Dynamic DNS can't work, but I'm just throwing out another option for consideration.

> The service for ddns allows me to connect to my home network. If I try to connect port 80 I just get the login screen for my router, no problems there.

You didn't say what IP address you use when connecting to port 80.  But since you said that right after talking about using DDNS, it sounds like you're talking about using your public IP address.  If that is actually the case, the last paragraph of [Daniel B's answer](http://superuser.com/a/1121138/401839) is a quite valid warning.  Consumer grade routers are notorious for not having sufficient security for their web interfaces, so find the option that specifies that your web interface should be accessible only using the wired LAN connection.  (Trust neither connections from the Internet, nor Wi-Fi.)

Comment: Thanks for the extended reply! And yes I deliberately did not mention the IP number on the WAN side which is 203.0.113.256 ;-)
The ZyXEL is using port 2222 for SSH or it at least informed me that it is using port 2222 at the moment I forwarded port 22. What I do not know is if this port number is also available on the WAN side.
Daniel B's answer is relevant but I cannot oversee why. Today I tested the connection from an outside location and was not able to make any contact. I made inquiries with my IPS.

Comment: Yes, of course your IP is 203.0.113.256.  Especially since the last octet maxes out at 255.  I presume you didn't mean to end the last comment with "Intrusion Prevention System", but rather, "Internet Service Provider".  You might benefit from network sniffing/snooping; check your router for such support.  Otherwise, "netstat -na" can help show what connections have been established.  Mainly, the way to check if an SSH connection is available is to try making a connection.  If you want more information, give us more question marks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you already helped me a great deal. Now I know that ddns is working (see remark at my original message) I'm going to try a SSH connection from the outside. I will keep you informed on my progress.
I will follow up on your remark on network sniffing/snooping. But "netstat -na" will only show me the connections on the PC where it is running. I will have to look up the ZyXEL documentation for this.
ISP, yes, Internet Service Provider.